# Laravel тестирование подписчиков на события

Tags: laravel, юнит-тесты

Мне нужно протестировать обработчик события создания модели. У меня есть много подписчиков (subscribers) на это событие, но мне нужен тест только одного из них. В каждом подписчике у меня есть метод `createdUser`

```
public function subscribe() {

    return [
        'eloquent.created: ' . User::class          => 'createdUser',
    ];
}


public function createdUser(User $user) {
    // некоторые действия
    SomeJob::dispatch($user);
}
```

Вопрос - что нужно сделать, чтобы при возникновении вышеописанного события не отрабатывали другие обработчики? По сути мне нужно ограничить слушателей события

Answer (score 0):

Тут отличные примеры как фейкать то что вам неоходимо)

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#queue-fake

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но в документации идет речь об указании каких слушателей нужно фейконуть. А меня интересует противоположное поведение - мне нужно фейконуть все, кроме одного слушателя. Да, можно перечислять всех, но это будет похоже на говнокод, если я буду фейкать 20+ слушателей, а при добавлении нового нужно будет править все тесты